# How to overlay point density (ggplot2) on OSM tile in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, spatial

I have question regarding my R script:
How do I overlay a point_density using google map or osm tile as background in R?
1) This works fine, but is not what I want:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map("Vilnius", zoom = 14, source = "osm", color = "bw")
mapPoints <- ggmap(map)
p<-ggplot(geotag@data, aes(Y, X))
p + stat_density2d(aes(fill= ..level..), alpha =0.5, geom="polygon") + geom_point(aes(Y, X), colour="red", data = geotag@data, alpha = .5)
```

2) if I instead use a osm tile as background the point density is distorted (unfortunately I cannot show illustrate an image). It seems that the point density function does not recognize the point distribution and creates a symmetric overlay:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map("Vilnius", zoom = 14, source = "osm", color = "bw")
mapPoints <- ggmap(map)
mapPoints + stat_density2d(aes(fill= ..level..), alpha =0.5, geom="polygon") + geom_point(aes(Y, X), colour="red", data = geotag@data, alpha = .5)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
OID_    Y   X
0   25.29315500000  54.68288700000
0   25.29375600000  54.68260200000
0   25.28416600000  54.68472200000
0   25.29776900000  54.68051900000
0   25.29549400000  54.68064800000
0   25.25535200000  54.67742600000
0   25.29541800000  54.68429700000
0   25.29751100000  54.68445600000
0   25.29541800000  54.68429700000
0   25.29541800000  54.68429700000
0   25.29751100000  54.68445600000
0   25.29751100000  54.68445600000
0   25.29751100000  54.68445600000
0   25.29751100000  54.68445600000
0   25.28865900000  54.68074300000
0   25.28943200000  54.67457100000
0   25.29133200000  54.68690000000
0   25.29176000000  54.68873800000
0   25.28049400000  54.67952800000
```

what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you provide the dataset `geotag@data` (or the spatial dataframe that it came from)? This is just a guess, but the distortion might be in the first graph. `ggmap(...)` sets the aspect ration to 1:1 to *avoid distortion*. You don't do that in you second snippet. Try adding `+coord_fixed()` to the last statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Calling your sample `df`:

[image]

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map("Vilnius", zoom = 14, source = "osm", color = "bw")
mapPoints <- ggmap(map)
mapPoints + 
  stat_density2d(data=df,aes(Y,X, fill= ..level..), alpha =0.5, geom="polygon") + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(Y, X), colour="red", alpha = .5)
```

The problem was that, in the first snippet, the default dataset is set to `geotag@data` in the call to `ggplot(...)`, whereas in the second snippet the default dataset is defined internally in the call to `ggmap(...)`. In that case you have to explicitly define the (local) dataset, and the X and Y mappings, in the call to `stat_density(...)`.

Comment: It seems the instruction to call the Open Street Map doesn't work anymore under the new ggmap library.  I am getting the following error from the `get_map` above:
`In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
  cannot open URL 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=25.2522284950317,54.6712512196609,25.3071601356567,54.7030039563636&scale=31000&format=png': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'`